# Text version of website on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, text

I have a small problem. I've made a website with HTML CSS and jQuery, but I ran into a problem regarding the appearance of the website on an iPhone. When a user chooses the text-version of the website, he will see only `index.php` without another site's parts.

I would like to disable text-version sites on iPhone. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: I've never heard of 'text version' on iPhone. What is it?

Comment: It's a functions, where you can disable all javascript, jquery, and CSS, so you can see text only. On iphone, you can enter that site. Is here a possibillity to disable text version?

Comment: Looks similar http://www.mochasoft.dk/ifiles/text.gif

Comment: No, you can't do that, unless you have no HTML ... which would be a really bad idea (unless you ask the fanbois of some JS frameworks that are popular at the moment).

Comment: No, no, I use only menuSprybar.js which is constructing dropdown menu. But if I disable it, it should display menu like unordered list. But in text version the menu disappear

Comment: O, right. In that case, get a better menu script—one built by a developer who's heard of progressive enhancement.